# Java, App Insights: "I/O Exception: Invalid Argument or cannot assign requested address" only when I run using docker. No error locally with gradle

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, azure-application-insights

i have a java spring app that runs just fine locally with gradle, but when i run the image version of it, i get a strange error that i am not sure how to resolve or debug

```
docker run -it --rm myregistry.azurecr.io/my-app:latest
```

is the command that i get the following error on:

```
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://rt.services.visualstudio.com:443: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
```

ive found out thru googling that this url https://rt.services.visualstudio.com:443 is associated with Application Insights (azure logging) which is one of my dependencies. does this mean something is wrong with logback?

the thing is, when i run with gradle, i see trace logs in the app insights instance i am trying to log to, so i know that connection is working outside of docker.

one thing to note is that in the deployed dockerized instance, i see the same logs on startup as the successful local gradle output, but then it dies after it sets the profile. maybe meaning that it is dying during the tomcat initialization.

what to do/try here?

Answer (score -1):

this ended up being due to a web proxy issue, switching networks or creating a proxy rule are solutions.